# Creating 2d coordinate system programme using OOP

Tags: c++, function, oop, void

I am writing a code to calculate & show the length of line in 2d coor system. However there are some error in my codes that im not sure on how to fix them. The error when i compiled is as shown in the attached picture.[CODING ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aND8I.png)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

class Line
{ private:
 int x1, y1, x2, y2;
 public:
 Line() : x1(0), y1(0), x2(0), y2(0) // default constructor 
 {
 Line ( int a, int b, int c, int d ) // constructor
 {
  x1 = a, y1 = b, x2 = c, y2 = d;
 };

 void setLine() ; // mutator function
 void getLine() const; // accessor function
 double getLength() const; // returns length of a line
}

void Line :: setLine()
{ cout << "Enter x-coordinate and y-coordinate of first endpoint : ";
 cin >> x1 >> y1;
 cout << "Enter x-coordinate and y-coordinate of second endpoint : ";
 cin >> x2 >> y2;
}
double Line :: getLine() const
{ cout << "\nThe endpoints of the line are : ";
 cout << "( " << x1 << ", " << y1 << " ) and ";
 cout << "( "<< x2 << ", " << y2 << " )" << endl;
}
double Line :: getLength() const
{ return sqrt ( pow(( x1 - x2), 2) + pow ((y1 - y2), 2) );
}
int main()
{ Line myline{ 2, 3, 4, 5};
 myline.getLine();
 cout << "Length of the line = " << myline.setLength() <<endl;
 cout << "Edit the line : " << endl;
 myline.setLine();
 myline.getLine();
 cout << "Length of the line = " << myline.getLength() <<endl;
 return 0;
}
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include the errors copy-pasted *as text*, and please add comments on the lines where you get the errors.

Comment: Please note the first warning in the posted link. You should start by replacing the command line option `-std=c99` with `-std=c++17` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `setLength` method which is not defined, I believed you intended to call `getLength`. Also your error message is low quality and unreadable.

Comment: Check your brackets they are messed up.

Answer (score 0):

your getLine function defined void in class

```
void getLine() const; // accessor function
```

and you have implemented as double return type:that you haven't defined in class

```
double Line :: getLine() const
```

change this line from double to void . And you don't have setlength function in your class check with that. you also forget to close `"{"` for default constructor. `";"` also forget at end of class. Extra ";" after constructor okay here is your working class

```
class Line
{
private:
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;
public:
    Line() : x1(0), y1(0), x2(0), y2(0) // default constructor 
    { }
    Line(int a, int b, int c, int d) // constructor
    {
        x1 = a, y1 = b, x2 = c, y2 = d;
    }

    void setLine(); // mutator function
    void getLine() const; // accessor function
    double getLength() const; // returns length of a line
};
```

Comment: changed all of these but the code is still not working

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a very bad try to write some C++ code (full of syntax errors an bad writing errors). I suggest you follow a C++ tuto before trying this...

For your piece of code, this should work, but if you don't understand why this works and your code doesn't, go and take at least one c++ lesson:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

class Line
{ 
private:
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;
public:
    // default constructor 
    Line() : x1(0), y1(0), x2(0), y2(0)
    {
        // empty brackets needed
    };
    
    Line ( int a, int b, int c, int d ) : x1(a), y1(b), x2(c), y2(d) // constructor
    {
        
    };

    void setLine() ; // mutator function
    void getLine() const; // accessor function
    double getLength() const; // returns length of a line
}; // need ';' after class definition

void Line::setLine()
{ 
    cout << "Enter x-coordinate and y-coordinate of first endpoint : ";
    cin >> x1; 
    cin >> y1;
    cout << "Enter x-coordinate and y-coordinate of second endpoint : ";
    cin >> x2;
    cin >> y2;
}

void Line::getLine() const  // here is void not "double". Be carefull of copy past
{
    cout << "\nThe endpoints of the line are : ";
    cout << "( " << x1 << ", " << y1 << " ) and ";
    cout << "( "<< x2 << ", " << y2 << " )" << endl;
}

double Line::getLength() const
{ 
    return sqrt ( pow(( x1 - x2), 2) + pow ((y1 - y2), 2) );
}

// main can't be inside a class
int main()
{ 
    Line myline{ 2, 3, 4, 5};
    myline.getLine();
    cout << "Length of the line = " << myline.getLength() <<endl; // getLength, not setlength
    cout << "Edit the line : " << endl;
    myline.setLine();
    myline.getLine();
    cout << "Length of the line = " << myline.getLength() <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```